# scala - dispatch example not working

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I'm following the very first example in the [dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html)docs -

```
    val svc = url("http://api.hostip.info/country.php")
    val country = Http(svc OK as.String)
    for (c <- country)
      println(c)
```

I do not get any output printed. When I change it to below to make blocking call then I get the output.

```
val res = country()
println(res)
```

Need help with this.

Full program-

```
import dispatch._
object DispatchTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val svc = url("http://api.hostip.info/country.php")
    val country = Http(svc OK as.String)
    for (c <- country)
      println(c)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think is blocking.. res is still a Future no ? try println(res.get)

Comment: to me it works perfectly as is... and it should, because the `for` comprehension wraps the `println` command in the `Promise` object, so it will be executed only when the `c` value is available

Comment: what version of dispatch are you using? can you show your build.sbt or whatever?

Comment: Anyway it looks to me like a question more appropriate to the [dispatch mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/dispatch-scala)

Comment: pasting my build.sbt above in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm, not sure here, but maybe the problem is that your main thread is finished so fast, that background thread (in which Dispatch works asynchronously) has no time for taking action?

To check this you may try to insert a delay:

```
for (c <- country) // Here we spawn a background thread!
  println(c)

Thread.sleep(500) // So let's wait half a second for it to work
```

Of course, in real program you should never need to do this.

Another option for delay is simply a `readLine()` in the end of main.

Comment: you can also check if your code works, when you paste it in the sbt-console

Comment: Yes this is the case. I get the output when I add the delay. Thanks!

Comment: you might need to increase the delay in case your connection is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

It works here:

```
scala> import dispatch._
import dispatch._

scala> val svc = url("http://api.hostip.info/country.php")
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
svc: com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilder = com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilder@2f823290

scala> val country = Http(svc OK as.String)
country: dispatch.Promise[String] = Promise(-incomplete-)

scala> for (c <- country)
     |   println(c)

scala> BR
```

Note that `BR` which appeared after the prompt.

Are you sure the country wasn't printed somewhere but you didn't notice because it was mixed up with other output?

Comment: I'm running it as a main function. I have updated my question.